# Double Pyramid Pattern : Not Getting desired output

Tags: c

I am not getting the desired output for my C program can anyone please have a look on the code and help me to rectify the error ?

Desired output and actual output of my code is:

[image]

My Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
int i,j,k;
int blank=0;
int lines = 6;
char symbol='A';
int temp ;
int diff[7]= {0,1,3,5,7,9,11};
k=0;

for(i=lines;i>=0;i--)
{
   printf("\n");
   symbol = 'A';

   for(j=i;j>=0;j--)    
        printf("%c ",symbol++);

   blank = diff[k++];   

   for(j=0;j<blank;j++)
        printf(" ");    


   symbol = 'F' - (blank/2);

   if (blank== 0)
       temp = i-1;
   else
       temp = i;

   for(j=0;j<=temp;j++)  
       printf("%c ",symbol--);

}
getch();
}
```

Comment: That link is blocked for me from here - can you vocalise the problem in the question?

Comment: Where is your included headers?

Comment: please look through this link.. its a Design pattern problem .. I cannot vocalise it. https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-sGrJo3x5ohQ/Ugy-fIyYvoI/AAAAAAAAABA/oncVpNpzCnA/s665/img.jpg

Comment: Maybe one " " isn't wide enough? In the places where no letter should be but a space should you aren't adding additional one I think. Can you count the spaces in output between the "F" and "F"? Cause I think there are only 2 instead of desired 3 (2 for the padding 1 instead of the letter).

Comment: It's a problem in designing patterns, not a design pattern issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your have written the code in a right way. You have to change the line

```
for(j=0;j<blank;j++)
    printf(" ");
```

to

```
for(j=0;j<blank;j++)
    printf("  ");   // increase one more space
```

And also try to avoid using `void main()`.Here is your edited code;

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,k;
    int blank=0;
    int lines = 6;
    char symbol='A';
    int temp ;
    int diff[7]= {0,1,3,5,7,9,11};
    k=0;

   for(i=lines;i>=0;i--)
   {
       printf("\n");
       symbol = 'A';

       for(j=i;j>=0;j--)    
           printf("%c ",symbol++);

       blank = diff[k++];   

       for(j=0;j<blank;j++)
           printf("  ");    


       symbol = 'F' - (blank/2);

      if (blank== 0)
          temp = i-1;
      else
          temp = i;

    for(j=0;j<=temp;j++)  
        printf("%c ",symbol--);

   }
return 0;
}
```

And do not forgot to include headers.

Comment: Down-voter must have to leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you're printing the wrong number of blanks. And the number you need can be worked out with a small piece of arithmetic.

Secondly, you don't need that messy calculation to work out the first symbol to print out after the blanks because you've already worked it out.

(editted so downvote can be withdrawn)

Comment: Please could the downvoter explain the down vote

Comment: @haccks Sorry? there's no requirement in stack overflow to spoonfeed the answer to people

Comment: Actually I just want to withdraw my down vote.

Comment: @haccks: click on the down button again to do that

Comment: No dude, its too late to do this. I can withdraw only after an edit.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here

```
for(j=0;j<blank;j++)
    printf(" ");    
            ^
            A
```

You are printing only a single space it should be **two**.So that one space corresponds to the alphabet and another to the actual space

```
   printf("  "); 
           ^^
           A(space)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use more blank spaces

Use 0, 2, 6... so on

Answer (score -1):

Your "diff" array is too small. You're accounting for the missing characters on the left side of the pattern, but not on the right side. Try making the first three elements `{0, 2, 6...}` and see if that works, and then work on extrapolating the correct pattern from there